# Process.Start run Application giving ODBC Error

Tags: c#, service, process, odbc

I have created a service in .Net which execute XYZ.exe which is in another folder as per time scheduled which fetch data from data base and write data to a  file using ODBC DSN. I have installed the service on my laptop (Win 7) it work's fine NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM privileges. When i install same service on Win 8.1 and Win 10, the process executes but the XYZ.exe the file got created but fails to write data to the file giving error as '[Microsoft][ODBC Drive Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'. But when i execute XYZ.exe manually it run successfully and writes the data in the files. I have tried giving access to Service. The Process/Service got execute using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM privileges. Following is the code

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = this.m_FilePath;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath);
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

It seem Rights problem to execute the XYZ.exe. I have tried various option.

Comment: ODBC setups unless set as global are user specific

Comment: Created System DSN for sql server database with SQL Authentication. But same issue.[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XYZ" requested by the login

Comment: Any of this on a remote machine?

Comment: it don't got u r point.

Comment: If you're trying to run something where say the database is held on a network drive, or such, system doesnt have rights to do that..

Comment: The database is on the local machine itself (Win 10). When i run my XYZ.exe run manually it create file with data. But when i run through service it give database error.

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx there maybe aspects of your app you hadnt considered such as temp folders

Comment: I have created SystemDSN. I work's on some on the machine